# Adding Image to Grid C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

My problem is that the image that I am setting to my grid is not appearing, the only thing appearing is the black background, so I know the grid is working. I am a noob, and I am very confused. Thanks for the Help :)

Code:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static String ImgNameMole = "C:/Users/MonAmi/Desktop/mole2.png";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GridMain();
        }

        private void GridMain()
        {
            Grid grid_Main = new Grid();
            MainWindow1.Content = grid_Main;
            grid_Main.Height = 350;
            grid_Main.Width = 525;

            grid_Main.Background = Brushes.GreenYellow;

            CreateImage();

        }

        private Image CreateImage()
        {
            Image Mole = new Image();
            Mole.Width = 25;
            Mole.Height = 25;
            ImageSource MoleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgNameMole));
            Mole.Source = MoleImage;
            return Mole;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you populate the grid?

Comment: @New Pin What do you mean?

Comment: You have created a CreateImage function but you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: Where do you define the content of the grid?; where do you fill it

Comment: Even if I put "CreateImage();" in the grid methid it still does not work

Comment: If you are using WPF you would have use WPF Pack Uris. See this question as an example. You would also need to add the image to your project as a Resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowhere in your code you are calling `CreateImage()`, so:

```
var img = CreateImage();
Grid.SetRow(img, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(img, 0);
grid_Main.Children.Add(img);
```

assuming that you have added at least one row and one column to your grid.