# How to display my images in a 4 by 4 grid using c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Currently my images just go down vertically, I want 4 images to display  horizontally in each row, I've tried few suggestions on here but can't seem to get it working to work, its quite confusing to me as a beginner.

```
foreach (MyWCF.dogs c in lc)
            {
                RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                row.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Auto);
                g.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
                StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
                sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                Image i1 = new Image();
                using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
                {
                    using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ms.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
                    {
                        writer.WriteBytes((byte[])p.images);
                        writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
                    }
                    //var image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.SetSource(ms);
                }
                i1.Source = image;
                i1.Height = 100;

                sp.Children.Add(i1);

                Grid.SetRow(sp, gridRef);
                g.Children.Add(sp);
                gridRef++;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**(Trying again with the Microsoft code explicitly included. I presume its OK to point to S.O. answers instead of copying an pasting the entirety of the S.O. answer here )**

Perhaps the tutorial [Grid Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=netframework-4.7.2) : ***"Defines a flexible grid area that consists of columns and rows."*** will help. Then, this S.O. question [Adding Image to Grid C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742262/adding-image-to-grid-c-sharp) shows how to add images to a WPF grid.

Here is the material from the **Grid Class** post:

The following C# example demonstrates how to create a grid. In this case, the grid defines three ColumnDefinition elements and four RowDefinition elements that host child content.

```
// Create the application's main window
mainWindow = new Window();
mainWindow.Title = "Grid Sample";

// Create the Grid
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
myGrid.Width = 250;
myGrid.Height = 100;
myGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
myGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
myGrid.ShowGridLines = true;

// Define the Columns
ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);

// Define the Rows
RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef3 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef4 = new RowDefinition();
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef3);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef4);

// Add the first text cell to the Grid
TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
txt1.Text = "2005 Products Shipped";
txt1.FontSize = 20; 
txt1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
Grid.SetColumnSpan(txt1, 3);
Grid.SetRow(txt1, 0);

// Add the second text cell to the Grid
TextBlock txt2 = new TextBlock();
txt2.Text = "Quarter 1";
txt2.FontSize = 12;
txt2.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
Grid.SetRow(txt2, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(txt2, 0);

// Add the third text cell to the Grid
TextBlock txt3 = new TextBlock();
txt3.Text = "Quarter 2";
txt3.FontSize = 12;
txt3.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
Grid.SetRow(txt3, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(txt3, 1);

// Add the fourth text cell to the Grid
TextBlock txt4 = new TextBlock();
txt4.Text = "Quarter 3";
txt4.FontSize = 12;
txt4.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
Grid.SetRow(txt4, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(txt4, 2);

// Add the sixth text cell to the Grid
TextBlock txt5 = new TextBlock();
Double db1 = new Double();
db1 = 50000;
txt5.Text = db1.ToString();
Grid.SetRow(txt5, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(txt5, 0);

// Add the seventh text cell to the Grid
TextBlock txt6 = new TextBlock();
Double db2 = new Double();
db2 = 100000;
txt6.Text = db2.ToString();
Grid.SetRow(txt6, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(txt6, 1);

// Add the final text cell to the Grid
TextBlock txt7 = new TextBlock();
Double db3 = new Double();
db3 = 150000;
txt7.Text = db3.ToString();
Grid.SetRow(txt7, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(txt7, 2);

// Total all Data and Span Three Columns
TextBlock txt8 = new TextBlock();
txt8.FontSize = 16;
txt8.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
txt8.Text = "Total Units: " + (db1 + db2 + db3).ToString();
Grid.SetRow(txt8, 3);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(txt8, 3);

// Add the TextBlock elements to the Grid Children collection
myGrid.Children.Add(txt1);
myGrid.Children.Add(txt2);
myGrid.Children.Add(txt3);
myGrid.Children.Add(txt4);
myGrid.Children.Add(txt5);
myGrid.Children.Add(txt6);
myGrid.Children.Add(txt7);
myGrid.Children.Add(txt8);

// Add the Grid as the Content of the Parent Window Object
mainWindow.Content = myGrid;
mainWindow.Show ();
```